# Django 1.4 - ManyToMany field looking like User permissions field in user auth

Tags: ajax, django, django-models

Is there any way to change the view of many to many field in admin ?

I mean what should I do to change the view of normal ManyToMany field:

[image: Many To Many normal look]

to look like this:

[image: User Auth many To many field]

PS.
I found that site in google:
https://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-filtered-fields/
But last update was in 2009, so i believe that there is other way to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using the [`filter_horizontal` `ModelAdmin` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal):

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    filter_horizontal = ["my_m2m_field", ]
```